# How to enable global search in custom component in Joomla 2.5

Tags: search, joomla2.5

I have just created some Joomla 2.5 components and now I want to make them searchable from the Joomla main search. What do I need to do to achive that?

Answer (score 1):

You must create custom finder plugin. Look at this tutorial http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2012/item/671-Developing-a-Smart-Search-Plugin